# Correct way to make reader/writer from/to files in Go

Tags: file, go

I have this type for example:

```golang
type Matrix [][]int
```

And a file like this, that holds the Matrix data:

```
Lines: 2
Columns: 3
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

What is the correct way to save/load something like that in Go? How do I take advantage of the Reader/Writer interfaces? Os is that not a use case for that? I could only think of this:

```golang
func (m *Matrix) Read(filename byte[]) (n int, err error) {
  data, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
  // Parse data using split, etc and modify "m"
  return len(data), nil
}

func (m *Matrix) Write(filename byte[]) (n int, err error) {
  b := strings.Builder()
  // Get the data from "m" and populate the builder

  ioutil.WriteFile(filename, b.String(), 0666)
  return len(data), nil
}
```

But that doesn't look right, as I'm not taking advantage of the interface or the os.File type (who's a Reader), and that I need a Matrix instance already created to populate it. How do I do it correctly?

Comment: If you look at the `io.Reader` and `io.Writer` interfaces, they do not take filenames as arguments; so while this type technically implements those interfaces, it does so in a way that makes it completely incompatible with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The io.Reader and io.Writer are read and write interfaces on a byte stream.  You need functions to encode and decode a Matrix on a byte stream.

Use the io.Reader and io.Writer interfaces from the Matrix package instead of implementing the interfaces. Leave the implementation to *os.File and so on.

It's typical to write a constructor function when reading a value:

```
// ReadMatrix creates a new Matrix from the data in r.
func ReadMatrix(r io.Reader) (*Matrix, error) {
  var m Matrix
  data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r)
  // Parse data using split, etc and modify "m"
  return &m, nil
}
```

... and to have a method for writing:

```
// Write writes the contents of the matrix to w.
// Use ReadMatrix to read the data in the format 
// written by Write.
func (m *Matrix) Write(w io.Writer) error {
  bw := bufio.NewWriter(w)
  // Get the data from "m" and write to bw.
  return bw.Flush()
}
```